# Transcoding to webm with ffmpeg audio problems

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, webm, vp8, transcode

For the past few days, I have been trying to get my lossless .mov video(that has an audio track) to a .webm format.

Some info on the video & audio is that the fps is 30. Also the audio track has about 3-5 seconds of silence/blank audio before you start hearing some music.

My problem is that is seems during the transcoding to webm, it strips away this blank audio because when I go to play the video, the audio starts right away.I've also notice that it jumps right away to ~4 seconds in the video. When i play it on the browser, it jumps to that moment in the timeline. If I try to scrub to the beginning, the video ends.

I've have figured somethings out.

1. This is just a webm problem. This does not happen with ogv or mp4
2. It only happens if they is blank audio in the beginning of the audio track.

I am using ffmpeg with the libvpx and libvorbis librarys and I am doing just the basic command line setup

```
ffmpeg -i "infile" "outfile.webm"
```

Comment: It would help to see the output from ffmpeg when you transcode the video.